# Jordan Form - Online Resources

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form, online-resources

Can anyone recommed a good resource (preferably video lectures) for learning the theory and algorithm of jordan form? I can only find videos that cover it very roughly.

Comment: Math doctor bob is great! He has a video on this very subject

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MTVqx1wh3Hs from googling "math doctor bob Jordan canonical form." Have you tried searching around on google?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I found his website

Comment: The real question is "why?"  The Jordan form is a useful theoretical tool, but it doesn't have much practical application.

Answer (score 0):

I have some good pdfs But I could not upload here. If you give your mail id or something I would send you.

Comment: How can I contact you in private?

Comment: my fb https://www.facebook.com/sani.chattopadhyay.14

Comment: Sent you a message on facebook chat with my email. Thank you.